# C# Try Catch and return back to prompt

Tags: c#, error-handling, console, try-catch

I have a try catch block that when it catches an exception I want it to return back to the ReadLine() so the user can try again to enter a valid selection

```
Console.Write("CSV File: ");
string csvFile = Console.ReadLine();            
try
{
    List<DictionaryLabels> values = csvRead(csvFile);
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CSV File not found \nPress any key to contiune");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Look up `while` loops

Comment: You are misusing the try catch concept. What you should be doing is checking if the file exists, then parsing it out to "values".

Comment: @Ethilium This is an [exogenous exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/); The file can always disappear or be locked between a `File.Exists(csvFile)` and the subsequent `File.Read(csvFile)`.

Comment: @Quantic You are right. I'm used to working with stationary files. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to the problem might work, but it does not follow the concept of programming. Try-catch blocks should be used whenever the situation is unexpected instead of the "might happen" scenario.

One way to handle this is described in the code below: You will get first input from the user & validate, if the file exists. Once this is confirmed, You can try to open it. If it fails (e.g. the file does not contain text in CSV format), You should throw an exception.

If it condition in `while( condition )` won't be false ( ! File.Exists() ), the loop will run again and again.

```
using System.IO;

Console.Write("Please enter the path for file:");

string lPath = Console.ReadLine();

while(!File.Exists(lPath))
{
    Console.Write("File has not been found. Please enter new path:");
    lPath = Console.ReadLine();
}


try
{
    List<DictionaryLabels> values = csvRead(lPath);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool valid = false

while(!valid)
{
//Rest of the code
}
```

And you set valid to true at the end of the try and remove the readline from the catch (thanks to Quantic for pointing out my omission).

Comment: And remove the `Console.ReadLine();` inside the catch. Would be clearer if you showed a proper implementation.

Comment: I didn't want to show the whole implementation because it looks like a homework, so I just wanted to give a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.Write("CSV full path File: ");
        string csvFile = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!ValidateCsv(csvFile))
        {
            Console.Write("Retype full path CSV File: ");
            csvFile = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static bool ValidateCsv(string csvFile)
        {
           bool isPathTrue = false;
           FileInfo csvFileInfo = new FileInfo(csvFile);
           isPathTrue = csvFileInfo.Exists;
           return isPathTrue;
        }
```